# "Reply" link missing from comments

Tags: views, comments

I am new to Drupal and I am a bit confused right now.

I can't understand why 'reply' link is missing from here [image]

any suggestions ?

Have read [this](https://drupal.org/node/373649), but no luck :(

Comment: Are you using a custom theme?  It might be hiding the link for whatever reason.  Are you using a custom distribution of Drupal?

Comment: yes, I am using a custom theme. By default this link is visible ?

Comment: Do a search in the theme's template.php for 'reply' and see if it is being removed from the links array.  Also, check if your theme is implementing it's own comment.tpl.php.  It might be doing something to alter the links in there as well.